# Copy-Item in PowerShell; The given path's format is not supported

Tags: windows, string, powershell

I'm relatively new to PowerShell, and I was trying to copy files using a text file formatted like this:

```
file1.pdf
dir1\dir2\dir3\dir 4

file2.pdf
dir1\dir5\dir7\di r8

file3.pdf
...etc.
```

Where the first line of each entry is a file name, and the second is the file path from C:\Users. For example, the full path to the first entry in the file would be:

```
C:\Users\dir1\dir2\dir3\dir 4\file1.pdf
```

The code below is what I currently have but I'm getting the error: 'The given path's format is not supported.' and another error after that telling me it can't find the path, which I assume a result of the first error. I've played around with it a bit, and I'm getting the impression that it's something to do with passing a string to Copy-Item.

```
    $file = Get-Content C:\Users\AJ\Desktop\gdocs.txt
    for ($i = 0; $i -le $file.length - 1; $i+=3)
    {
        $copyCommand = "C:\Users\" + $file[$i+1] + "\" + $file[$i] 
        $copyCommand = $copyCommand +  " C:\Users\AJ\Desktop\gdocs\"
        $copyCommand
        Copy-Item $copyCommand

    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can read the file in chunks of three lines, join the first two elements to form a path and use copy-item to copy the files.

```
$to = "C:\Users\AJ\Desktop\gdocs\"

Get-Content C:\Users\AJ\Desktop\gdocs.txt -ReadCount 3 | foreach-object{
    $from = "C:\Users\" + (join-path $_[1] $_[0] )
    Copy-Item -Path $from -Destination $to
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this (inside the cycle):

```
$from = "C:\Users\" + $file[$i+1] + "\" + $file[$i] 
$to = "C:\Users\AJ\Desktop\gdocs\"
Copy-Item $from $to
```

`$from` and `$to` are arguments for `Copy-Item` cmdlet. They are bound to parameters *-Path* and *-Destinattion*. You can check this via this code:

```
Trace-Command -pshost -name parameterbinding { 
   Copy-Item $from $to
}
```